# Scheduled a local notification some minutes early

Tags: java, android, notifications, localnotification

**This is prayer time Local notification. We will get a notification when it will match prayer time.
The problem is, It always come some minutes late.
So to overcome wanted to make notification some minute early.**

**StartNotificationreciever.class**

```
for (int i=0; i<prayerNames.size(); i++){
                String prayerName = prayerNames.get(i);
                if (prayerName.equals("Fajr")) {
                    String time = prayerTimes.get(0);
                    String[] array = time.split(":");
                    int hour = Integer.parseInt(array[0]);
                    String timeMinuit = array[1];
                    String[] array2 = timeMinuit.split(" ");
                    int minuit = Integer.parseInt(array2[0]);
                    String finalNotificationText = "View namaz time in " + locality + " location - " + prayerTimes.get(0);
                    Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
                    Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();
                    calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
                    calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuit);
                    calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                    calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
                    calendars.add(calSet);
                    notificationTextArrayList.add(finalNotificationText);
                }
```

NotificationReciever.Class

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

                        NotificationChannel mChannelFajr = notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(FAJR_CHANNEL_ID);

                        if (mChannelFajr == null) {
                            mChannelFajr = new NotificationChannel(FAJR_CHANNEL_ID, fajrChannelName, importance);
                            mChannelFajr.setDescription(notificationText);
                            mChannelFajr.enableVibration(true);
                            mChannelFajr.enableLights(true);
                            mChannelFajr.setLockscreenVisibility(VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
                            mChannelFajr.setSound(soundUri, audioAttributes);
                            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannelFajr);
                        }

                        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, FAJR_CHANNEL_ID);

                        builder.setContentTitle("FAJR NAMAZ")  // required
                                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_darshika_logo) // required
                                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                        R.mipmap.ic_darshika_logo))
                                .setContentText(notificationText) // required
                                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                                .setAutoCancel(true)
                                .setLights(Color.MAGENTA, 500, 500)
                                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                                .setSound(soundUri)
                                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                                .setTicker(context.getString(R.string.app_name));

                    } else {

                        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, FAJR_CHANNEL_ID);

                        builder.setContentTitle("FAJR NAMAZ")
                                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_darshika_logo) // required
                                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                        R.mipmap.ic_darshika_logo))
                                .setContentText(notificationText)  // required
                                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                                .setAutoCancel(true)
                                .setSound(soundUri)
                                .setLights(Color.MAGENTA, 500, 500)
                                .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                                .setTicker(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
                    }
                    notification = builder.build();
                    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

**This is where the notification is generated.**

```
if (targetCal.getTimeInMillis()>System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                int requestCode = (i) * 100;
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);
                intent.setAction("com.shiamomin.sjmmj.MY_NOTIFICATION");
                intent.putExtra("notificationText", finalNotificationText);
                intent.putExtra("requestCode", requestCode);
                intent.putExtra("notificationType", notificationType);
                Log.d("notificationType", String.valueOf(notificationType));
                // Loop counter `i` is used as a `requestCode`
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                        requestCode,
                        intent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                AlarmManager mgrAlarm = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                mgrAlarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,targetCal.getTimeInMillis(),
                        pendingIntent);
                Log.d("time", String.valueOf(mgrAlarm));


                Log.d("targetTime", String.valueOf(targetCal.getTime()));

                intentArray.add(pendingIntent);
```

**what changes should i do.**

Comment: Not sure why you are calling `prayerTimes.get(0);`, I believe it should be `prayerTimes.get(i);`.

Comment: I am having a array list of prayer. I have 5 set 5 prayer . so i am using for loop.         
             for (int i=0; i<prayerNames.size(); i++){
                    String prayerName = prayerNames.get(i);                                                    That is why i am using prayertimes.get(0). for first prayer and prayertimes.get(1). for second prayer and so on.

Comment: @HB. Hey i have edited the question for better understanding do chack out.

Comment: What is the value of `String time = prayerTimes.get(0);`?

Comment: @HB value of String time = prayerTimes.get(0); is the time of prayer in this case its 5:44am

Answer (score 1):

## Avoid `Calendar`

Well, I don't do Android programming, and it seems you have not really given enough info, but I can tell you this much: The terrible `Calendar` class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes.

To get the current moment as seen the JVM’s current default time zone, use [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) and call [`now()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#now()).

```
ZonedDateTime nowZdt = ZonedDateTime.now() ;  // Current moment as seen in the JVM’s current default time zone.
```

Track your time-of-day values as [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html) objects rather than as text.

```
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.of( 15 , 00 ) ;
```

Adjust the current moment to that time-of-day.

```
ZonedDateTime nextPrayerZdt = nowZdt.with( localTime ) ;
```

Notice that *java.time* uses [immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). Rather than alter (mutate) the original object, we generate a new object with values based on the original.

Make sure that this new moment is in the future.

```
boolean isFuture = nextPrayerZdt.isAfter( nowZdt ) ;
```

If you want a moment a few minutes ahead of that, subtract.

```
ZonedDateTime beforeNextPrayerZdt = nextPrayerZdt.minusMinutes( 3 ) ;
```

And check again that this is in the future.

```
boolean isFuture = beforeNextPrayerZdt.isAfter( nowZdt ) ;
```

Where you must interface with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, you can convert back and forth between the legacy and modern classes. Look for new `to…` and `from…` methods added to the old classes — at least in regular Java, I do not know about Android. See:

- [`GregorianCalendar::toZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#toZonedDateTime())
- [`GregorianCalendar.fromZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#from(java.time.ZonedDateTime))

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

Comment: Thank you, Really appreciate the way you taught me this concept. The problem is the app is in the final stage so will be difficult to change Calendar to ZonedDateTime in whole project.

Comment: @MukhtarAli Where you must interface with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, you can convert back and forth between the legacy and modern classes. Look for new `to…` and `from…` methods added to the old classes — at least in regular Java, I do not know about Android. See [`GregorianCalendar::toZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#toZonedDateTime()) and [`GregorianCalendar.fromZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#from(java.time.ZonedDateTime)).

Comment: Ohhh. I got it . I have Changed the things . Really happy for this solution. Thank you sir .@Basil Bourque